# How to open the crontab of another user in my editor of choice?

Tags: cron, editors

I work in a team. We have a CentOS Linux machine. There's a user there called `www`. We run cron jobs as that user, i.e. I can type `sudo -u www crontab -e` to see/edit the crontab, and my teammates do the same. However, I like to use nano as my editor, but the crontab opens in vim, because that's the `EDITOR` for the `www` user.

Is there a way I can get the crontab to open in nano, without changing the `EDITOR` setting for the `www` user? (e.g. via the addition of some additional command line parameter?) My teammates will continue to expect vim to open when they themselves run `sudo -u www crontab -e`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the `EDITOR` variable as an argument to `sudo`:

```
sudo -u www EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```